# Ion date time ‘Ok’ and ‘Done’ buttons not display properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I wanna implement ionic date time (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)
to my project.

[date time problem here are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKeQ.png)

But ı cannot see date time buttons. I don't understand what the actual problem is.

This is output of ionic info command.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.10.2
npm   : 3.10.10 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm a" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

It will give time with format.

*I hope it will help you.*